# Cannot determine true health of SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I've got a very new laptop running Windows 10 and recently it decided to do some self-updates and after the hard drive became unstable. Windows kept trying to scan and repair the disk but it froze at 0% all the time whilst there were corrupt Windows files all over the place, causing major problems with things such as explorer.exe.

I've recently done a reset on the laptop and it seems to be working fine except HDSentinal shows a health of 22% on the SSD (Kingston) due to bad sectors. I've tried using another software like HHDScan which showed no errors or bad sectors & run Kingston's SSD Manager which shows a good health of the SSD whilst also running chkdsk without any issues.

Is this HDSentinal software just lying to me regarding bad sectors or can I find out another way?

Answer (score 1):

SSDs are supposed to reallocate bad sectors, the drive controller will take care of bad sectors, you can try CHKDSK on SSD but use it to repair system files not to fix bad sectors.

It means that when your OS tried to fix HDD's bad sectors it can cause trouble for HDD. So if you can disable all possible SSD HDD checks if possible.

SSD does not need checking, it either works or not.

This article might give you a good clue on how to use your SSD drive better:
https://lifehacker.com/5802838/how-to-maximize-the-life-of-your-ssd